# Vuetify Is there a way to disable/enable a v-text-field append-icon

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I have a form v-text-field with an append-icon to fire a method when clicked.

Is there a way to disable/enable conditionally this append-icon ?

I mean disable not hide.

(Vuetify version 1.5.24)

Comment: as far I know append-icon has no action by default. Are you declaring you own click handler? You can simply ignore action in it for you "disabled" state, are you?

Comment: Post a minimal code to see what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use icon slots to place `v-btn` which can be controlled. please check example below.

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="message"
  label="Message"
  type="text"
>
  <template v-slot:append-outer>
    <v-btn
      v-bind="attrs"
      disabled
      v-on="on"
    >
      <v-icon>
        mdi-menu
      </v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked! But somehow, I got error with `v-bind="attrs"` and `v-on="on"` then I have to remove them to fix the error

Answer (score 1):

You might solved that by now but this how I would do it:

```
<v-text-field
 v-model="value"
 :label="Title"
 :rules="item.IsRequired ? [rules.required] : []"
>
 <template v-slot:append-outer>
  <v-icon :disabled="checkValue(item)" @click="save(item)">
   mdi-content-save-outline
   </v-icon>
 </template>
</v-text-field>
methods: {
    checkValue(value) {
      if (!value) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```